# When sending an email, Cannot redeclare fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, gmail

I'm getting the following error when attempting to email.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PHPMailerAutoload() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\ISPSystem\mail\PHPMailerAutoload.php:24) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ISPSystem\mail\PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 31

Answer (score 0):

you use `require_once`  which include your file only one time so this function can not re declare .

```
require_once 'yourfilepath/yourfile.php';
```

so file link will be something like this

```
require_once . 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

more about `require_once`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

or check function exit or not exit then call this function

```
if (!function_exists('PHPMailerAutoload')) {
   function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
     {
     // your function code
     }
    }
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: I solved my problem.

Comment: my solution not work?

Comment: This happen due to the double repetition. Please check your code again.

Comment: this happen why i know that but if you use require_once then if you include many time then it will not problem